# How can we add 'required' attribute to a dropdown box in jsp page

Tags: spring, jsp, jsp-tags

How can we add `required` attribute to  a dropdown box in a JSP page? I added it in normal fields using `Required = required` keyword. But in dropdown, it is not working.

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label class="form-control-label" for="customer_category">Category</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <form:select class="select2" id="customer_category" path="category.id"> 
      <form:option value="0">Select a Category</form:option>
      <c:forEach items="${listCustomerCategory}" var="category">
        <form:option value="${category.id}">${category.name}</form:option>
      </c:forEach>
    </form:select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean select input?

Comment: show your code and were it's not working

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte yes jonathan.. In my form there is a dropdown field.   I want to ad Required = required attribute to it. ie if the user left that box empty and submit the form a message should appear..

Comment: @SangeethRayaroth 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_required.asp

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte.. I have updatd my code here.

Comment: The data inside the drop down box is coming from a table in the database

Comment: @user1 Hi , i  updated the code. And i want to know how can i make that dropdown mandatory inorder to submit the form

Comment: and you're saying adding the attribute, required="required" to the form:select element doesn't work? By the way, you forgot to mention this was a Spring project.

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention ..

Comment: It is a Spring Hibernate project

Comment: you should be able to do it by adding `@NotNull` annotation to `category.id` from the java code

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the answer, I just Changed this line

```
<form:option value="0">Select a Category</form:option>
```

to

```
<option value="">Select a Category</option>
```

Now it is working..